# Is there a method of getting the number of files in git repository with new/modified/deleted status?

Tags: python, git, zsh

I'm writing a Python script that prints a string describing the state of a git repository in the current directory. This is being used for creating a right-sided prompt in zsh. The output will look like the right side of this:

```
jared@Jareds-MacBook-Pro% ⌷                          master(+0, ~0, -0)
```

Right now, I'm trying to find a method of determining the number of new, modified, and deleted files in the repository so that I can update the counts in the string. I need to be able to do this either in Python 3 or through subprocess.call() or subprocess.check_output(). Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git status --porcelain | cut -c 2 | sort | uniq -c
```

Thanks @crea1 for the correction

Comment: Nice, but it didn't seperate between modified and deleted, so I modified your command a bit: `git status --porcelain | cut -c 2 | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: The output of `git status --porcelain` looks easily parseable for my needs. Also cera1's cleanup pipes work very nicely. I'll play around with the possibilities this offers and either use it or parse the original output inside Python instead, but this is definitely the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the solution in Python, note that the output of `git status --porcelain`:

```
 M modified_file.txt
 D deleted_file
?? untracked(new)file
```

Here is the code sample:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from collections import Counter

def count_git_status():
    command = ['git', 'status', '--porcelain']
    pipe = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE)
    status = Counter(line.split()[0] for line in pipe.stdout)
    return status

def main():
    status = count_git_status()
    print('Untracked: {}'.format(status['??']))
    print('Modified:  {}'.format(status['M']))
    print('Deleted:   {}'.format(status['D']))
```

#### Update

The output of `git branch --list`:

```
  bar
  foo
* master
```

To parse, we look for the line that starts with '*'. Here is the code to get the branch. With this you can construct the prompt:

```
def git_branch():
    command = ['git', 'branch', '--list']
    pipe = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE)
    return next((x.split()[1] for x in pipe.stdout if x.startswith('* ')), 'unknown branch')
```

Comment: Very elegant example code. I may use this as a reference for parsing. And today you taught be about the Counter class. Thanks.